# Alfresco Share Search 5.0a broken?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have tried out both OS X and Windows versions of Alfresco 5.0a. Every time I try searching in Alfresco Share I run into an error with the following message: "There was an error loading search results"
Is this a bug or is there a solution for fixing this?

Tomcat catalina.out shows the following:

```
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 08100023 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js': No enum constant org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchParameters.Operator.
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:204)
at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1364)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchParameters.Operator.
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
at org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchParameters$Operator.valueOf(SearchParameters.java:80)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.Search.queryResultSet(Search.java:679)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17._c_getSearchResults_20(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1127)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17._c_main_22(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1199)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js:1202)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_search_search_get_js_17.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:502)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:200)
... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct it looks like backward compatibility was broken for that extension (remove it and search will work ok) - we will fix that ASAP before the final 5.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco 5.0.a introduced a customizable default operator to combine search terms. Looks like the component building the query sets up an empty value. In `Search.java` it reads:

```
Map<Serializable, Serializable> def = (Map<Serializable, Serializable>)obj;
// ...
String defaultOperator = (String)def.get("defaultOperator");
// ...
if (defaultOperator != null)
{
  sp.setDefaultOperator(Operator.valueOf(defaultOperator.toUpperCase())); // 679
}
```

Allowed values `AND`  and `OR`. Look at the code responsible for building up the query. The problem is there. It may be an outdated extension.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that modification of search.get.config.xml in $ALFRESCO_HOME/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search/ broke Alfresco share search.